# Leave a review button only works on developer mode in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, app-store, review

I discovered just now that my button to "Leave a review" on the App Store only works on developer mode. I had done several tests and it was perfect but now that I'm testing it from the "Ready for sale" version it no longer works. The App Store app opens with the following message: "Connection to the App Store not possible".

Do you know why there's such a difference?

```
if let reviewURL = URL(string: "http://apps.apple.com/app/[AppName]/[AppID]?action=write-review") {
    Button(action: { UIApplication.shared.open(reviewURL) }, label: {
        HStack {
            Text("settings-button-review")
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            Spacer()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Was your app rejected initially, and then did you resubmit it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/EnvironmentValues/requestReview

Comment: Nope, my app wasn't rejected. It's only looks like a broken links!

Comment: @loremipsum Do you think my problem can come from the link where I use `app/AppName/AppID` instead of `app/AppID`?

Comment: I think you should just use the provided API.

Comment: I finally identified the problem, it's because I use `http` instead of `https`. But I don't know If I can use this kind of "secured" protocol without problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following URL:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=[APP-ID-HERE]&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&mt=8
```

Note - the "type=Purple+Software" - it is not the name of your product, but a code name for iOS applications.

Please remember that you should not manipulate user reviews by sending only positive reviewers to the store, otherwise your submission will be rejected.

itms-apps: does not work on the iOS Simulator, that is because simulator does not have App Store app to handle it.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer to use the "regular" link proposed by Apple. But if it doesn't work I'll try yours as well.